# Angular service calls a service by same interface/abstract class => cyclic dependency

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, interface, abstract-class

I wanted to call a service which calls a service. Both are injected and use the same interface/abstract class.

```js
export abstract class Service {
  abstract getTitle(): string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class BService extends Service {
  getTitle() {
    return "from B";
  }
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AService extends Service {
  constructor(private service: Service) {
    super()
  }
  getTitle() {
    return this.service.getTitle();
  }
}
@NgModule({
  providers: [{ provide: Service, useClass: BService }]
})
export class AModule {}
```

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ provide: Service, useClass: AService }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

```js
export class HelloComponent {
  title: string;
  constructor(service: Service) {
    this.title = service.getTitle();
  }
```

And I get:

```
Provider parse errors:
Cannot instantiate cyclic dependency! Service ("[ERROR ->]"): in NgModule AppModule in ./AppModule@-1:-1
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqoena

How can this be achieved without repeating myself?

Answer (score 0):

Change the AppModule.ts to the following

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, AModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, HelloComponent],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  providers: [AService] // <-- Just provide the service
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Also AService does not need to extend the abstract service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class AService {
  constructor(private service: Service) {
  }
  getTitle() {
    return this.service.getTitle();
  }
}
```

See working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eejf3d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

#### Update 21. Oct 2020

> I wanted to call a service which calls a service. Both are injected and use the same interface/abstract class.

Which means

```
ServiceA extends Service
ServiceB extends Service
ServiceB is being injected into ServiceA
ServiceA will be called from Component
(ServiceB will also be called from Component)
```

The scenario above is implemented [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-eejf3d?file=src/app/code.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much! Unfortunately, now the `AService` is omitted.  Adding `return "A says:" + this.service.getTitle();` does not show up.

Comment: There is no mention of your snippet in your initial post

Comment: Yes, but I wrote "I wanted to call a service which calls a service". I have mentioned this snippet to show that your example does something different, in case there where any doubt.

Comment: In the StackBlitz example I've adapted the console.log to `console.log("A says: " + this.service.getTitle());` and the string gets printed out as expected.

Comment: Thank you. "I wanted to call a service which calls a service. Both are injected and use the same interface/abstract class." Does your example really do that? I don't think so. It is possible in other languages like Java for instance.

Comment: Please check my latest update on my answer, this should be it

Comment: `Service` is just a representative an interface. And `AService` is a representative of an implementation. Your solution says: `AppComponent`/`app.component.ts` does care about the implementation, where it should not. It should take whatever `Service` is injected without further changes to it.